# passing value to JavaScript from JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
<%   if(empRecNum != null && !(empRecNum.equals("")))
        {
           empSelected=true;
        }
        boolean canModify = UTIL.hasSecurity("PFTMODFY") && empSelected;
%>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function add(){
        alert(canModify);
        df('ADD');
    }

</script>
```

I need to alert the canModify in my JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I use something like this:

```
<%
String s = "BOB";
%>
<script>
alert('<%= s %>');
</script>
```

The '<%= %>' tag lets you put in the value of the java variable.

Comment: You need to escape the string to block XSS attacks.

Comment: Yes, and the simplest way to do that is to use a JSON encoder.

Answer (score 3):

Get away from using scriptlets, use jstl and expression language and it would look like this:

```
alert( ${UTIL.hasSecurity("PFTMODFY") 
         && empRecNum != null 
         && !(empRecNum.equals("")
        }
      );
```

Comment: That will work **if** "UTIL" is a reference that's available in the request attribute map (or maybe the page attribute map; I can't recall whether that works implicitly or not). If it's just a variable declared in a scriptlet, then it won't work. I do agree with you however that scriptlets are horrid and in 2010 nobody should be using them.

Answer (score 2):

Do some thing like.

```
function add(){
        alert(<%=canModify%>);
        df('ADD');
    }
```